# How do I call a parent's class constructor with a var_args in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor, google-closure

I have this class

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {...*} var_args
 */
var Map = function(var_args) {
    // insert all pairs of parameters as objects in the map
};

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Map}
 * @param {...*} var_args
 */
var ExtendedMap = function(var_args) {
    goog.base(this, var_args); //<-- this obviously doesn't work!
};
goog.inherits(ExtendedMap, Map);
```

The problem araises given that `ExtendedMap` needs to extend a class (`Map`) which in it's constructor already has a var_args. How do I add my own constructor without messing up with the parent's constructor? I'm using the **google-closure compiler**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `goog.base`, it is just a method to make things easier. In this case you would call the Map's constructor directly and using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) instead of call:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Map}
 * @param {...*} var_args
 */
var ExtendedMap = function(var_args) {
   Map.apply(this, arguments);
};
goog.inherits(ExtendedMap, Map);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought of using that. Does the compiler still make the proper renaming?